# adding string to character array at specific position giving buffer overflow in c programming

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcat, strncpy

I am very new to c programming, and for a school assignment I need to write a programm that takes a string as input and add the letters “ay” to each word that starts with a consonant at the front of this word. It is hinted that this should be done with strncpy and strcat.

this is the code that I wrote:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {   
        char myString[50];
        char abc[26] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";
        char strA[50];
        char strB[50];
        char strC[150];
        char ay[3] = "ay";
        printf("** Welcome to the Double Dutch game **\nPlease enter a string: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &myString);
        int i, j;
        for (i=0; myString[i]!='0'; i++) {
            for(j=0; abc[j]!='\0'; j++) {
                if(abc[j] == myString[i]){
                    if(myString[i-1] == ' '){
                        strncpy(strC, &myString[0], i);
                        strncpy(strB, &myString[i], 40);
                        strcat(strC, ay);
                        strcat(strC, strB);
                        myString[0] = '\0';
                        strcat(myString, strC);
                        strC[0] = '\0';
                        strB[0] = '\0';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Result: %s", myString);
    }
```

When i run this code it keeps giving the error *** Buffer overlow detected ***: /home/a.out terminated. I cannot find the mistake that I made. Hopefully someone can help me.
Thanks

Comment: Change `char abc[26] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";` to `char abc[] = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz";` - Let the compiler do the leg work

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]s", &myString);` --> remove the `&`

Comment: What happens if the first character in the string is a consonant? `i` will be 0 and this `if(myString[i-1] == ' ')` check will go out of bounds.

Comment: `scanf(" %[^\n]s", &myString);` should be `scanf(" %49[^\n]", myString);`, the `%[]` conversion specifier is *not* a modifier for `%s` (many people seem to think it is, for some reason), it stands on its own. Adding a width helps prevent buffer overflow.

Comment: @SouravGhosh - The `s` is not required as well

Comment: @EdHeal right, I do not like scanf much, not used for ages, missed the details. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Indeed it is a tricky beast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &myString);
```

to this:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", myString);
```

since `%[^\n]` conversion modifier is not a modifier for `%s`, they are independent. As a result, you can discard it.

---

Tip: Add the size of your array - 1, to prevent a possible buffer overflow, like this: `scanf(" %49[^\n]", myString);`